# Formatting numpy arrays with vscode

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-code, formatting

Pretty new to coding, just wondering if there is a way to easily format numpy arrays (or any array for that matter) in VSCode to be in this stacked style?

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

At the moment I'm tabbing and spacing to get them stacked like that, its a pain.
Thanks for the advice

Comment: try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lmcarreiro.vscode-smart-column-indenter

Comment: For input an array does not have to be that neatly formatted.  Line indent matters, but not internal spacing. Most python aware editors help with indents.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you wrote this array yourself manually.

If this is a line in your code, please replace it with built-in numpy functions.

Instead of:

```
a = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Use this:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
```

Which outputs the same result.

Comment: Ah yes I just copied that as an example from a tutorial I was doing.  Lets assume they were not incremental and that I had to manually enter the elements rather than generate them.